# How to force manual merge for specyfic file (for whole repository)?

Tags: git, git-merge, gitattributes

I would like to avoid merging *.csproj files in git for all users. 
Is it possible (for ex. in .gitattributes) add something what always force users to check what they are merging (and make manual decision)?

Comment: `echo '*.csprog: !merge'` >>.gitattributes`.

Comment: Better yet: `echo "*.csprog" >> .gitignore; git rm --cached *.csprog; git add .gitignore; git commit`. You probably should just stop tracking IDE/build/tool artifacts...

Comment: Not really. Because I do some changes in this files and they are XML.